# Prototype reusable tableview cell rendering subviews poorly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

This is the second project I have had this particular problem on.  Earlier today I set up a tableview and prototype cell via the storyboard.  I added subviews with tag numbers so i could get them from the cellforrowatindexpath delegate method. The subviews though are not in the right place though when i run the app.  I use autosizing for layout and made sure to set the delegates. Has anyone had this problem?

POSSIBLY RELEVANT:  Sometimes when i leave the storyboard and come back, the subviews changed their frames so that they are flat (height = 0) or x has changed to like 1,500 randomly.  No clue why but this happened on the old project I had the problem with as well.  The old project I resolved the issue by resetting the frames of all the subviews in the cellforrowatindexpath method but I don't like that as a legit solution.

EDIT:  Here is some code and screenshots.

```
//MARK: - UITableview delegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 93.0
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7;
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("order") as? UITableViewCell
    println("cell: \(cell)")
    var cancel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as UIButton
     var price = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel
     var date = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as UILabel
     var address = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
    cancel.addTarget(self, action: "cancelOrder:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell!
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show storyboard, show code for cell, show code for how to reuse. Everything works properly there, you are doing something wrong

Comment: updated... There is not a whole lot going on especially w/ the code. As you can see though on the screenshot, all the UILabels are overlapping.  Infact, 2 of them are not even within the bounds of the cell anymore.  It seems to be a storyboard issue, not a code issue

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue recently. It seems to be a bug with autolayout for the content view in custom cells.

All I did was in the awakeFromNib for my custom cells reset the autoresizing mask and everything started working as expected.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```

Comment: So I just used a "prototype" cell in the storyboard(screenshot added to question) with a reusable Identifier.  No subclassing or XIBs/NIBs.  Does your advice still apply? If so, where should i put that code?

Comment: Actually considering your screenshot, I think it is the storyboard. I've also had this issue recently where things would just jump around in the storyboard after editing something else. As far as I can tell it is just a bug with storyboards in Xcode 6. I had to just move things back the way I wanted a couple of times but it's stayed put in the past few days. I'm fairly sure it's just a glitch in the current Xcode that will hopefully be fixed soon.